# Return in logical operators (&& return, || return)

Tags: javascript, return, shortcut, logical-operators

How can I do a 'return' in a logical condition?

It'd be useful in cases like these

```
checkConfig() || return false;
var iNeedThis=doSomething() || return false;

doJob() && return true;
[...] //do something else if fails (it not return)
```

instead of

```
if(!checkConfig()){return false}
if(!iNeedThis=doSomething()){return false}

if(!doJob()){//fallback}
```

This is and idea that I'd like to use
I don't understand why this is downvoted.

Comment: try `checkConfig() || false;`

Comment: No.............

Comment: @gurvinder372 no, I want to exit the function in that case

Comment: `return` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: besides... what makes your suggestion 'useful' anyway? Is it really that hard to do a condition?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi if I want to use it as an expression?

Comment: @musefan is shorter and more concise

Comment: @Francesco, then you will be fighting against the language, and you will lose.

Comment: At most you can do `return checkConfig() || false` but even then, I'd say that a function that _needs_ to do several things or exit immediately if one fails, may need to be re-though.

Comment: Even if you could, it is a gruesome side effect.

Comment: @Francesco: Well, `checkConfig() || r f;` is even shorter... will you be trying to do that next? Why don't you try writing code like a minimizer would create and see how much fun you have then

Comment: @musefan I think that something like `checkConfig() || return false;` is still very readable and user friendly to understand

Comment: @Francesco: Not really, because it doesn't make any logical sense what it is doing. `if(!checkConfig()) return false;` now that makes sense and is only 2 characters longer than what you are proposing. And thats the point, making it look less logical for the sake of 2 characters would be a bad feature

Comment: [The `throw` expression proposal](//github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions/issues/6) and [the `do` expression proposal](//github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions/issues/39) may set precedents for a `return` expression proposal. Remember that you can propose new language features to TC39.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You have to have something that evaluates as a *value* on each side of a logical operator.

Use an `if` statement if you want to test something before returning.

Comment: More accurate second paragraph: _“You need a valid production of_ [LogicalORExpression](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-LogicalORExpression) _to the left, and of_ [LogicalANDExpression](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-LogicalANDExpression) _to the right of an `||`. For `&&` it’s_ LogicalANDExpression _and_ [BitwiseORExpression](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-BitwiseORExpression) _(plus parameterized productions like_ LogicalORExpression\_Yield, LogicalORExpression\_Await, _etc.). `return true` is a_ ReturnStatement, _i.e. not a valid non-terminal here…”_. “Evaluating as a value” isn’t directly a requirement.